# Different ways of reading and writing files in C#

Tags: c#, file, stream

I am trying to understand different ways of reading and writing files with their advantages and disadvantages. Like when to use TextWriter/TextReader when File.Create or StreamReader/StreamWriter
FileStream etc.

When to use what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `File.*` static methods are just simple ways of constructing new `FileStream`s, `FileWriter`s etc. They're very useful - I generally use File.* in preference to explicitly calling the constructors unless I need some behaviour which isn't catered for.

The main *crucial* point is:

- For binary data, use `Stream`
- For text data, use `TextWriter`/`TextReader`

If you start trying to read binary data with `TextReader`, bad things will happen.

Comment: I forgot XML. What is for XML?

Comment: The XML APIs tend to have methods to load files directly, e.g. `XDocument.Load`

Answer (score 5):

[Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) is an abstract class that represents a sequence of **bytes**.

- [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) derives from Stream and allows you to treat a file as a Stream.

[TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx)/[TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) are abstract classes that allow you to read/write **characters**.

- [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)/[StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) derive from TextReader/TextWriter and provide implementations to read/write from/to a Stream (which can be a FileStream) using an [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx).

The `File.*` static methods are just convenience methods to simplify the creation of a FileStream.

Answer (score 3):

I'm certainly nowhere near an expert on this topic, but I do just want to point out that `TextReader` and `TextWriter` are base classes (abstract ones, I believe) used by many other classes for handling different kinds of I/O. `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` should be used when you're actually dealing with `Stream` objects containing text, such as the `FileStream` for a text file. But a `TextReader` need not necessarily deal with streams; take the `StringReader` class, for example, which also inherits from `TextReader` and just reads a simple string.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying mechanism that each of these processes use is the same, so none is "better" than the other.

The difference is in the ease of performing certain tasks.  For example File.CreateText returns a StreamWriter, which is functionally no different than manually creating a StreamWriter and using that to write to a file.  It just takes less code.  (I think of it as a shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the static helper methods `System.IO.File.WriteAllByte(...)`, `.WriteAllText(...)` `.WriteAllLines(...)` and their corresponding `.ReadAllByte(...)`, `.ReadAllText(...)`  and `.ReadAllLines(...)` methods.  If I don't have any reason to muck with a stream I use them because they're quick getter/putter file IO methods.